# Use awk or sed to capture & parsing text

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I've some text output like the following:

```
+-------------------------+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Site                    | SSL | URL                            | Path                                       |
+-------------------------+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| samplerds.test          |     | http://samplerds.test          | /Users/user01/Paths/samplexx1              |
| wpo.test                |     | http://wpo.test                | /Users/user01/Paths/wpo                    |
+-------------------------+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to parsing the text above using `awk` or `sed` to transform them into the following:

```
samplerds
wpo
```

Cheers

Comment: Anything you tried yet? Is the TLD always  `.test`?

Comment: @pLumo yes, I've tried several hours and yes I can say the TLD is always .test. Because the Path (directory name can be different to the domain name which give me so much headache so far)

Comment: And *what* did you try in that hours? It will help you the most if we see your attempt and explain why it did fail.

Comment: Is that _really_ what you have? That looks like the result of a database query. Can't you just skip printing the headers? Also, with `mysql` for example, the ASCII table characters are not printed when you pipe the output somewhere. Is that what you're using maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk -F '[ .]' 'NR>3 && !/^\+/ {print $2}' file
samplerds
wpo
```

or add the subdomain as field separator:

```bsh
awk -F ' |\.test' 'NR>3 && !/^\+/ {print $2}' file
```

or with `gsub` to make it also work when you have subdomains:

```bsh
awk 'NR>3 && !/^\+/ {gsub("\.[^.]*$","",$2); print $2}' file
```